# Rails 4 - How to optimize this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Lets say that I have this code:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

    def action1
        @books = ...
        @books = @books.someaction param1, param2
    end

    def action2
        @books = ...
        @books = @books.someaction param1, param2
    end

    def action3
        @books = ...
        @books = @books.someaction param1, param2
    end

    ...

    def action84
        @books = ...
        @books = @books.someaction param1, param2
    end
```

I have this action I run on an instance variable quite often. I thought of putting it on an `after_action` filtering, but that happens after rendering, so that is no good.

How could I optimize this?

**Disclaimer:** This is a exaggerated case, not a real one. Just trying to make more graphic the problem. I do not have a controller with **84** actions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you use all those actions if the logic is same across all the actions. However, Have you tried `before_action`? i.e collect all the common instance variables in one method that executes before the action executes.

Comment: Im not saying that **all** the actions use it. There could be others that do not use it.

Comment: I can not user a **before** action, because it is the action itself which executes the main code, and it is on the result of that code that I want to execute my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `render` just for that particular controller to always do your thing before rendering. Something like this:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def action1
    @books = ...
  end

  def action2
    @books = ...
  end

  private

  def render(*args)
    if @books.present? && param1.present? && param2.present?
      @books = @books.someaction param1, param2
    end
    super
  end

end
```

Comment: Interesting. This kinda looks like an `after_action_before_render` filter :)

Comment: This is a great solution. I had no idea you could do this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a private function in your controller, and use it in your actions:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def action1
    @books = ...
    foo
  end

  def action2
    @books = ...
    foo
  end

  def action3
    @books = ...
    foo
  end

  ...

  def action84
    @books = ...
    foo
  end

  private

  def foo
    @books = @books.someaction param1, param2
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, then i don't think you have any other option, except extracting it to a `before_filter` method, and make sure that you declare all necessary variables in other `before_action`, that runs before.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [decent_exposure gem](https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure). This should allow you to just do something like:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    expose(:books) { books.someaction param1, param2 }

    def action1
        books = ...
    end

    def action2
        books = ...
    end

    def action3
        books = ...
    end

    ...

    def action84
        books = ...
    end
end
```

Comment: The whole gem for that seems a little overkill, after seeing *Unixmonkey* solution, but definitely an interesting gem which I didnt know. I will keep a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: I would agree and use @Unixmonkey's solution, it seems much better unless you want the other benefits this gem provides. If you want to use the gem, I'd say go this route (since you are already using for other things). Otherwise, don't add it only for this feature.